# Average a range using an (i,j) format

Tags: vba, excel

I'm tearing my hair out. I've tried every variation I can think of on:

```
cell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average((i + 24, j + 2),(i + 70, j + 2))
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `range(cells(i + 24,j + 2),cells(i + 70, j + 2))`?

Comment: if it really is only two items... `(Cells(i + 24, j + 2) + Cells(i + 70, j + 2)) / 2`

Comment: You're not telling VBA you're referring to cells here. That's why you're getting an error. It's just doing (say `i = 1`): `Average((25,3),(71,3))` which doesn't make sense in VBA. Either of the above two above comments should work. (If you use @Chrismas007's, just take out the entire Function and just divide the two cells).

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't clear - this is not two cells but the range inbetween - 46 cells.

Comment: Thanks but i wasn't clear, sorry - its the range inbetween rather than just two cells.

Comment: I wasn't clear, sorry - it's the range inbetween these two cells I want, rather than the two cells themselves.

Comment: Then look at @findwindow first comment as it is the format you want.

Comment: I've also tried variations on: Cells(i + 100, j + 3).value = [Average (Cells(i + 24, j + 2) : Cells(i + 70, j + 2)] with no avail..

Comment: I'm being slow maybe.. but i cant get any variation on Application.WorksheetFunction.Average.range to work..

Comment: @DanS See my answer for correct syntax

Comment: If you are getting errors with the answers below then there are other problems. Post more of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the syntax slightly and set the base values of **i** and **j**:

```
    Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, v As Double

    i = 1
    j = 1
    cell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Cells(i + 24, j + 2), Cells(i + 70, j + 2))
    MsgBox cell
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

I hope this version makes my comment a little more understandable:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim cell As Double, r As Range
    '
    '   The values of i, j below are just demo values
    '
    i = 1
    j = 1
    Set r = Range(Cells(i + 24, j + 2), Cells(i + 70, j + 2))
    cell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(r)
    MsgBox i & "," & j & vbCrLf & r.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf & cell
End Sub
```

Comment: @findwindow  My tiny program just shows **2** things:  *1* both I and J must be assigned a value and    *2* the syntax must correct.

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student but findwindow is correct - i and j are assigned as part of a larger sheet and all suggestions so far give me 'expected array' or 'syntax error'.

Comment: @findwindows he put it together only to show proof of concept. To do so he needed to make a few assumptions. The OP should then be able to take the one line and incorporate what he/she needs.

Comment: Thanks you again Gary's Student but it is still throwing an error highlighting RANGE and saying 'expected array'. Strangely I can't get the capital R's to stay up - they turn lower-case unlike above..odd.

Comment: @DanS  Be sure to include the line of code that `Dim`s *r* as `Range`

Comment: I have.. I added a . before range and it stoped throwing an error but the cell returned VALUE#

Comment: I have run your sub as a seperate sub and am now getting 'unable to get the average property of the worksheet funtion class'

Comment: @DanS  In this context you will get that error message if there is no data to average............that is if all the cells in the range ae empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Something in the huge code was playing silly buggers. I followed your suggestions in a separate sub which I call after everything else is done and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you want:

```
Cells(i + 100, j + 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(i + 24, j + 2), Cells(i + 70, j + 2)))
```

Comment: @DanS what is the value of `i` and `j`?

Comment: They identify cols and rows within a certain block which is repeated many times across the same sheet. Sorry if my terminology is basic!

Comment: @DanS Run your code and either do a `MsgBox i` or `Debug.Print i` and the same for `j` and tell me what that shows.

Comment: @christmas007 It will say, 14 for i and j will increase in jumps of 10 as it moves through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
cell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(range(Cells(i + 24, j + 2),cells(i + 70, j + 2))
```

This is the full change that findwindow suggested.